# How to proceed further in this 8 queen algorithm?

Tags: c++, c, backtracking

The code and output is working fine before backtracking but I am not able to proceed for backtracking. What to do do after unplacing? It is giving the output of first 4 queens only means before backtracking.

```
    #include <iostream>
    #include <conio.h>
    using namespace std;
    int recu(int i,int k);
    void place(int i,int k);
    void unplace(int i,int k);
    int q[8][8];
    int row[8];
    int column[8];
    int c[15];
    int d[15];
    int totalqueens=0;
    int s;

    int main()
    {
        for(int i=0;i<8;i++) //Flags for rows,columns and diagonals
        {
        row[i]=0;
        column[i]=0;
        c[i]=0;d[i]=0;
        }
        for(int i=8;i<15;i++)
        {
        c[i]=0;d[i]=0;
        }
        int i=0;
        int k=0;
        recu(i,k);


      for(int i=0;i<8;i++)
      {
          for(int k=0;k<8;k++)
          {
                if(q[i][k]==1)
                {
                   cout<<"(";
                   cout<<i;
                   cout<<",";
                   cout<<k;
                   cout<<")";
                }
           }
     }

    getch();
    return 0;
}

int recu(int i,int k)
{ 
     if(totalqueens==8)
     {  goto print; }
     if(k<8)
      {
          if(column[i]==0 && row[k]==0 && c[i+k]==0 && d[i-k+7]==0)
           {
             place(i,k);

             s=k;
             k=0;
             recu(i+1,k);
           }
           else
           { 
             recu(i,k+1);
             unplace(i-1,s);
            //**I am not able to proceed further**
           }

      }

print:
    ;
}

void place(int i,int k)
{     
    totalqueens++;
    q[i][k]=1;
    row[k]=1;
    column[i]=1;
    c[i+k]=1;
    d[i-k+7]=1;
}

void unplace(int i,int k)
{
    q[i][k]=0;
    row[i]=0;
    column[k]=0;
    c[i+k]=0;
    d[i-k+7]=0;
    //cout<<"before call";
    recu(i,k+1);
    //cout<<"working";
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code only gives out one solution.
u r not put the output part in the right place.

try like this:

```
void print()
{
      for(int i=0;i<8;i++)
      {
          for(int k=0;k<8;k++)
          {
                if(q[i][k]==1)
                {
                   cout<<"(";
                   cout<<i;
                   cout<<",";
                   cout<<k;
                   cout<<")";
                }
           }
     }
}
```

make that to be one method. and then, in your recu method, modify to:

```
if(totalqueens==8)
{
    print();
    return;
}
```

Keep in mind that DO NOT use goto sentence. It is very ugly and may cause unknown problems.

Answer (score 0):

You backtrack when not all queens have been placed and you cannot place another queen. You backtrack as follows:

1. See if the last placed queen can be placed in a later spot. If so, place it there and stop backtracking. (Resume placing.)
2. Remove the last placed queen.
3. If there are no queens left, stop. All solutions have been found.
4. Go to step 1.